# Webpack - how can I identify and exclude some package from rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm using [react-stdio](https://github.com/mjackson/react-stdio) server to render react.js on the server side.

Webpack rendered javascript file has these lines:

```
 /***/
 /* 49 */
 /***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__)
 »·/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(global) {/* global window */             
 »·'use strict';                                                                 

 »·module.exports = __webpack_require__(50)(global || window || this);           

 »·/* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */}.call(exports, (function() { return this; }())))  

 /***/ },                                                                        
 /* 50 */                                                                        
 /***/ function(module, exports) {
```

The problem is that `react-stdio` dislikes the `window` variable: `react-stdio` returns to me `ReferenceError: window is not defined`. So, questions:

1. How can I understand which dependency is marked as #49?
2. How can I eliminate this `window` variable from the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `target: 'node'` to your webpack.config. According to the webpack docs:

> Target: "node" Compile for usage in a node.js-like environment (use require to
>   load chunks)

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'backend.js'
  }
}
```

If this doesn't work, try this tutorial - [Backend Apps with Webpack](http://jlongster.com/Backend-Apps-with-Webpack--Part-I) (the example was taken from it).